# Shuffle all DIVS with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, shuffle

What I need done is:
Original State:

```
<div class="shuffledv">
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
</div>
<div class="shuffledv">
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div>
<div id="6"></div>
</div>
```

After Shuffle:

```
<div class="shuffledv">
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="1"></div>
</div>
<div class="shuffledv">
<div id="5"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="6"></div>
</div>
```

The Divs within the first div stay there but get shuffled, and the same happens for the second div with the same class.
To shuffle divs inside a specific div I use something like this:

```
function shuffle(e) {               // pass divs inside #parent to the function
            var replace = $('<div>');
            var size = e.size();

            while (size >= 1) {
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
                var temp = e.get(rand);      // grab a random div from #parent
                replace.append(temp);        // add the selected div to new container
                e = e.not(temp); // remove our selected div from #parent
                size--;
            }
            $('#parent').html(replace.html()); // add shuffled divs to #parent
}
```

Called lie this: `shuffle('#parent .divclass')`
Where all Divs with class `divclass` are inside `#parent`
I think it should start out something like

```
function shuffle() {        
            $(".shuffledv").each(function() {
```

and then do some form of the original function, but I've just gotten completely lost at this point. I have no idea how to go forward from here. Please let me know if you need anymore info.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bv3MN/1/). Essentially what we do is for each of the container `shuffledv` divs we find all children divs and store them in a list, then we remove them from the DOM, e.g.:

```
$(".shuffledv").each(function(){
        var divs = $(this).find('div');
        for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) $(divs[i]).remove();
```

Then I grabbed the Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-a-javascript-array) to randomise the list of our divs, and finally we append them back to the parent container, like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) $(divs[i]).appendTo(this);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is not the most effective solution. for example if your divs contain many iframes, this will make the browser reloads all the iframes, should find a way to shuffle them without removing/appending.

Comment: My ide is complaining about $ not being defined. I tried to add jquery to javascript. I'm using replit. Any advice please?

Answer (score 3):

Gave this an initial run through:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    // Cycle over each .shuffledv HTMLElement
    $(".shuffledv").each(function () {
        // Remove all divs within, store in $d
        var $d = $(this).find("div").remove();
        // Sort $d randomnly
        $d.sort(function () { return Math.floor(Math.random() * $d.length); });
        // Append divs within $d to .shuffledv again
        $d.appendTo(this);
    });
}());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uYyAH/2/

Comment: Tried this one but $d.sort line did nothing.